# Is there a constructor for arrays that uses arguments other than length?

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

Search engines just return tons of irrelevant pages when searching for "array constructor", so here I am.

I want to know if there is a constructor for making an array (of primitive types or just objects) that can take arguments other than length.

```
int[] intArray = new int[length];
```

or

```
RandomClass[] otherArray = new RandomClass[length];
```

is there anything more that can be customized in an array except length at its creation?

for example `int[] intArray = new int[](length, somethingElse);`

Comment: Not that I know of, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What other parameters do you think there are?

Comment: First of all array isn't a class so it doesn't have any constructor and what do you mean by `somethingElse`?

Comment: (An array has essentially two attributes:  It's class and it's size.  There's nothing else to control/set, other than the actually array element values.)

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve anything specific, just wanted to know if there's more to it and potentially improve my code. It drives me crazy that I can't find any documentation on the default array constructor.

Comment: Thats because arrays are special,  they don't have constructors

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3

Comment: @RichardTingle - They just *think* they're special, 'cause they're snobs.

Comment: @RichardTingle What do they have then? That's what I'm most probably looking for

Comment: It has new int[length]; theres really not any more to it (unless you're refering to initialisation at creation as per Andres' answer)

Comment: Basically, you can think of arrays as classes whose constructors are "native", with no Java source.  Rather than using the [`new` bytecode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.new) which is used for regular Java objects (and which invokes a constructor for the chosen class), they have the [`newarray` bytecode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.newarray) which goes straight into the JVM.

Comment: (Your "Spidey sense" is not that far off, though.  How arrays are handled is one of the major irregularities of the Java language and JVM architecture.  It could have been done much more uniformly.)

Comment: @Hotlicks Would make a nice answer

Answer (score 6):

You can construct it and initialize it at the same time:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 1):

In a word; no

An array is (conceptually) just a number of boxes in which you can place objects of a certain type. Both the number and type are specified already and there's nothing else to add to such a simple concept.